# getting messaged id's from gmail is very slow

Tags: c#, .net, gmail-api, google-api-dotnet-client

i have created class library using .net version 4.5 and language is c#. it is taking more than minutes to fetch just 6 emails from gmail API.
below code i m using for getting mail details

```
public Message GetMailDetails(GmailService service, string EmailId, string MessageID)
{
            try
            {
                var a = service.Users.Messages.Get(EmailId, MessageID);
                a.Format = UsersResource.MessagesResource.GetRequest.FormatEnum.Metadata;
                var retMessage = a.Execute();


                //a.Format = UsersResource.MessagesResource.GetRequest.FormatEnum.Metadata;
                //retMessage = a.Execute();
                //a.Format = UsersResource.MessagesResource.GetRequest.FormatEnum.Minimal;
                //retMessage = a.Execute();
                //a.Format = UsersResource.MessagesResource.GetRequest.FormatEnum.Raw;
                //retMessage = a.Execute();
                return service.Users.Messages.Get(EmailId, MessageID).Execute();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return null;
            }
 }
```

Comment: Sounds like an issue with your internet connection.  Not sure how we can answer I cant see anything wrong with the code you have posted.  It could be anything.

Comment: do you have any idea, how can i implement partial response in this code so that i could extract only those parameters which i need, rather than extracting all data?

Comment: according to the Gmail API [docs](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list#response) the `list` return resources contain only an id and a threadId - so at least the `list` call is not returning all the data.

Comment: @ShubhamAngne try using the Fields parameter it will allow you to limit the response.

Comment: i have added code i am using to get mail details can you help passing fields parameter @DaImTo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is try to work with something called [Partial response](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/performance#partial-response) the easiest way to test this is to go through the try me page [try me](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/get?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22userId%22%3A%22me%22%2C%22id%22%3A%221742abfd3a4f16c5%22%2C%22fields%22%3A%22id%2C%20threadId%22%7D) you will need a message id to test this

A full response from message.get would look like this

```
{
  "id": "1742abfd3a4f1c5",
  "threadId": "1742a8c81816e51",
  "labelIds": [
    "CHAT"
  ],
  "snippet": "I&#39;m surprised nobody questioned me when I said that the tag was 2 weeks old, but clearly has questions from longer than 2 weeks ago. {:",
  "payload": {
    "partId": "",
    "mimeType": "text/html",
    "filename": "",
    "headers": [
      {
        "name": "From",
        "value": "Axxxx"
      }
    ],
    "body": {
      "size": 139,
      "data": "SSYjMzk7bSBzdXJwcmlzZWQgbm9ib2R5IHF1ZXN0aW9uZWQgbWUgd2hlbiBJIHNhaWQgdGhhdCB0aGUgdGFnIHdhcyAyIHdlZWtzIG9sZCwgYFybHkgaGFzIHF1ZXN0aW9ucyBmcm9tIGxvbmdlciB0aGFuIDIgd2Vla3MgYWdvLiB7Og=="
    }
  },
  "sizeEstimate": 100,
  "historyId": "6172496",
  "internalDate": "1598445048740"
}
```

By adding the fields paramater to your request fields=id,threadid the response then looks like this

```
{
  "id": "1742abfd3a4f16c5",
  "threadId": "1742a8c181816e51"
}
```

Basically you request only the fields of data you want to see.

## example

```
var request =  service.Users.Messages.Get(EmailId, MessageID)
request.Fields = "id,threadid";
var response = request.Execute();
```

fields can be a bit tricky to get to work when you are trying to pick out stuff from arrays or list i really recommend testing it in the try me.

Comment: i made it work like this   
a.Format = UsersResource.MessagesResource.GetRequest.FormatEnum.Metadata;
                    List<string> headers = new List<string>();
                    headers.Add("Date");
                    headers.Add("Subject");
                    headers.Add("Cc");
                    headers.Add("From");
                    headers.Add("Bcc");
                    headers.Add("To");
                    a.MetadataHeaders = headers;